# What is the maximum amount of displayed cells in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make a graph-like interface where the `UICollectionView` is a grid with ideally 400x400 cells (pixels). I have noticed that when I increase the number of cells using this function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 2500
}
```

At large numbers, it chooses to display no pixels. For example, at 2500 pixels, it displays the cells; however at 6400 pixels, it displays nothing. Ideally, I would have 160,000 cells displayed at once, however, this number displays no pixels.

Does anyone know if there is a maximum limit, and if there is, are there any loopholes around this?

Comment: Considering the memory usage, you shouldn't make 160.000 cells, try to use 10 for example and just replace the content smoothly.

Comment: A `UICollectionView` is a terrible way to draw a graph. Why not actually draw the graph in a single view?

Comment: Well, the point of using a `UICollectionView` is because I am implementing basic line drawing algorithms used in Computer Graphics. So it is important to show the pixels.

Comment: How would you go about drawing pixels in a single view @maddy?